# Como agrupar sequências numericas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, machine-learning

Amigos,
Tenho um arquivo csv com 5k linhas no qual constam transações de compras. Existe um id para cada compra, ocorre que para um lote onde varias transações de compras são realizadas existe um id que começa sempre com a mesma sequência numérica, mas antes do final dessa sequencia ha um numero que identifica uma compra dentro denum lote. Exemplo:

A pessoa comprou 5 itens:

`000034200100`
`000034200200`
`000034200300`
`000034200400`
`000034200500`

Se essas sequencias vivessem nessa ordem seria maravilha, ocorre que essas sequencias vem espalhadas nesse arquivo de 5k linhas.

Como posso agrupar esses lotes de maneira a deixar tudo junto como no meu exemplo?
Quero fazer isso em **python** ok.

Pensei em clusters mas não sei se é boa ideia.

Comment: Você já tem algo desse código feito?  Consegue incluir um exemplo dos dados completos que precisam ser organizados? O resultado seria outro `.csv`?

Comment: Ainda não tenho nada em código pronto. Recebi isso ontem de um cliente e basicamente é um csv com essa coluna de id, descrição, origem, destino, valor, tarifa, e etc. A saida pode ser um csv ou um xlsx.

Comment: Qual é e astrutura do csv? da forma como vc fez a pergunta fica dificil entender o contexto, sugiro editar a pergunta e colocar um fragmento do csv para 'clarear' um pouco mais, tá meio obscuro. :-)

Comment: O csv esta separado por virgulas e abrindo no excel a primeira coluna é  o id, logo após vem descrição, quantidade, origem, destino, valor, tarifa..... É uma estrutura colunar comum, nada muito diferente das tabelas convencionais.

Comment: O arquivo tem muitas colunas e pra colocar aqui um pedaço vai ficar ruim, mas basicamente é uma tabela normal sem nenhum tipo de estrutura diferente.

Comment: Com a sua descrição nao da para entender como essas sequencias estão "espalhadas". Se quiser poste o csv (ou parte dele) em um storage qualqer (google drive, mega) ou nos temporary storages, tipo [Expirebox](http://expirebox.com/) ou [File Town](https://file.town/) e coloque o link aqui que tento ajudar. Estou aqui me divertindo com o python. :-)

Comment: Ok. Vou providenciar, mas quando disse espalhados, quis dizer que na coluna id esses numeros ( tal como eu descrevi) nao vem em sequencia, ou seja, as compras de um lote não vem com os ids em sequencia, mas vem fora de ordem. Se o cara compra 5 itens, os ids não vem em sequencia ordenada......entende?

Comment: Não, não da para entender assim, preciso conhecer a "estrutura" do csv, assim fica muito obscuro. Se na msg vc colcasse umas 2 ou 3 linhas do csv com um exemplo e a explanação, provavelmente eu entenderia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o número que identifica forem sempre os 3 últimos (ou um número fixos de digitos a partir do final)

```
l = ["000034200100", "000034200200", "000034200300", "000034200400", "000034200500"]
d = {} #Vamos salvar os resultados aqui
for numero in l:
    prefixo = numero[:-3] #Slice sem os 3 últimos elementos da string
    if not d.get(prefixo, False):
        d[prefixo] = [numero]
    else:
        d[prefixo].append(numero)
```

Isso vai gerar um dict separado por "prefixo" ou seja, os ids sem os números de lote, onde o valor de cada prefixo é uma lista com todos os IDs que começam com aquele prefixo, vc pode dar um `sort` nessa lista para ordenar ela